# Relative positioning on :hover leads to infinite repaint thrashing

Tags: javascript, css

I have a `<a>` tag, rendered as a button that I'd loved to move a pixel to the north on hover. However, I noticed an unwanted behavior when positioning the mouse cursor just so at the bottom edge, the hover gets triggered, and once the button is repositioned the hover is no longer active. This leads to an infinite repaint loop, as long as the cursor is in that position. It maxes out my CPU.

I understand why it's happening, yet, I'd love to find some more elegant solution, than wrapping it in another div that handles the hover, without moving itself.

Any ideas?

Edit: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/887at/) with exaggerated movement of 5px.

I've tried these (all trigger the same loopiness):

- position: relative; top: -1px;
- transform: translateY(-1px);
- margin-top: -1px; margin-bottom: 1px;
- border-top: none; border-bottom: 2px ... /* normally 1px all around */

Edit2: The border trick worked, but the bounding box does not move only the content.

Comment: The border trick should actually work; could you provide a demo, please?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Ndxtr/ -- a negative margin

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Ndxtr/1/

Comment: @BootstrapThemer, the negative margin does not work. If you position the mouse on the bottom row of the button, it will keep going in and out of hover state. I added some text after the div to show you that the negative margin actually messes with the whole page by making it repaint incessantly.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if I am understanding your question correctly but
try giving your div the class button and use the following code.
    $('.button').on('click', function(){
    $('.button').css('margin-top' , '15px');
});

Comment: Margin top makes it go towards the bottom of the page. Negative margin makes it go towards to top. However margin by itself will resize the element make the rest of the page jump as well.